# What was Smith's plan to take over Zion?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

Smith hacks himself into the body of Bane which is the first step he took for destroying Neo in the real world and also because the Oracle says he would eventually get into the real world. (That is what I recall anyway, please correct this if I am wrong)

My question is, **how would have have done this?** Smith gets into the real world, Zion. He plans on killing everyone and in the Matrix, he changes everyone to Smiths.

**Would he have just hacked into those jacked into the Matrix continually?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Smith, having successfully taken over large numbers of the humans and programs within the Matrix is, quite rightly, very concerned that Neo will fulfil his destiny and reboot the Matrix, resetting the system and presumably preventing Smith from fulfilling his wider goal of leaving the Matrix and taking over the machine city.

Smith isn't especially keen to 'take over' Zion, as much as he's looking for a way to hasten its destruction and kill Neo in the process, buying him extra time to work out a way to get out of the "zoo" and into the real world. That's why he tries to prevent him from meeting the Architect, why he kills the Oracle and why he's so keen (in Bane's body) to kill the real world Neo.

> **Neo:** *The program Smith has grown beyond your control. Soon he will spread
>   through this city, as he spread through the matrix. You cannot stop
>   him. But I can.*